# How can data vary pending how I view them

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have an odd case where when I look at the data through my SQL scripts I have one value, but if I look at the data directly `SELECT * FROM table` I get another value.

My first thought was parameter sniffing, but that didn't fix the issue. I'm not doing anything with the value at hand, except getting it with a stored procedure.

Example of the stored procedure.

> CREATE PROCEDURE example
>   (
>       @iRefProjectID int
>   )
>   AS
>       -- Prevent Parameter sniffing
>       DECLARE @projectID int
>       SET @projectID = @iRefProjectID
>
> ```
> SELECT iEntryType
> FROM table
> WHERE iEntryType IN (1,5,6)
> AND iProjectID = @projectID
> RETURN
> ```
>
> GO

Now one of the rows so extracted contains a '2', which when I look at it through the SP it is a '1'. It shouldn't have been picked at all being 2 != 1 || 5 || 6. Suddenly the 2 becomes a 1 and then "1" == 1.

Where should I look to kill this bug.

The rows in question
`SELECT * FROM table

3264427 2003-11-25 00:00:00.000 **2**   Udligning til afregning F83907  100625.00`

`Exec SP

3264427 2003-11-25 00:00:00.000 -100625.00  Udligning til afregning F83907  **1**`

Ahh .. found something. This rather looks like a Join bug.

Comment: Try to fully qualify the table server.user.table in the select.

Comment: I tried as you said - no change. Now I have dbname.dbo.table - same result, ofcourse I did it both on the SP and on my manual select no change of data I see. We are talking about the same identity row has 2 different values pending.

Comment: So the code you posted is not the same code you're running? I also see the sign is different too but you only select 1 column in the SP.

Comment: And try to avoid calling the table [table]. Try to avoid keynames in your naming.

Comment: And stopp thinking it is a bug. In 99 percent of the cases it is not a bug but the developer.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I killed this 'feature'. Seems I have a two to one relation between two tables. One of them being Type 1 and the other being Type 2, and each Type has a value recorded to it - one being + the other being -, so they balance each other out (debit, credit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such bug.

You probably have 2 tables with same name in different schemas. Example: `dbo.table` and `[DOMAIN\User].table`

Best practice is *always* qualify objects to avoid incorrect schema resolution.

There are other options such as:

- different databases
- different servers
- table is actually an unrefreshed view
- dirty read (as per Yves M. comment) because you have changed isolation level

Comment: I only have 1 database with this data, I'm looking solely on my developement machine and the local database. Data was refreshed/restored this morning and no it does not change during the day. Data is updated nightly from client systems.

Comment: Still no such bug. Something is wrong with objects or security if it's the same db etc. Do you not think someone would have noticed this by now if it *was* a bug?